# Getting warnings with SHA512 OpenSSL with unsigned char

Tags: c, openssl

I am playing with openssl in C and getting some warnings I like to get rid of and am unsure how to tackle it as the examples I had found seem to do what I am emulating.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char resSHA512[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char unhashed[1024];

    printf("Input string to hash: ");
    fgets(unhashed, sizeof(unhashed), stdin);
    unhashed[strcspn(unhashed, "\n")] = 0;

    SHA512(unhashed, strlen(unhashed), resSHA512);
    printf("\nSHA512: ");
    for ( i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++ )
    {
        printf("%02x", resSHA512[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I also got an alert that `SHA512` has been deprecated by open when I compile on my Mac using openssl I got through it's git repository.  I get no warnings in Linux unless I used the `-Wall` flag with `gcc`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am trying to learn new things!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're reading in to `unhashed` is a string, so you should declare it as an array of `char`.  That will address the warning with the string-related functions.

That leaves you with a warning when calling `SHA512` which expects an `unsigned char` for its first argument.  In this case you can safely cast the argument to `unsigned char *`.

The warning you see on Mac is because the entire OpenSSL library was marked deprecated on that OS in favor of its own crypto library.